# Using JPA for for the oracle table containing raw type as Primary key

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have an old table in an Oracle DB, having PK as RAW[18]. Now I'm migrating my project to use JPA inside of JDBC. what should be the Java type for Primary key to read the data from this table.

I tried using **byte[]** but its failing as

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02329: column of datatype LOB
cannot be unique or a primary key
```

Comment: What is RAW[18]? a name of the PK column? What you mean in using JPA inside JDBC?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri my requirement is to get the entries from this old table. RAW[18] is nothing but the date type of the primary key

Comment: Are you trying to generate a new table? The exception sure looks like it. Or are you trying to map the existing table to a JPA entity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map Oracle RAW datatype with corresponding Java type in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809540/how-to-map-oracle-raw-datatype-with-corresponding-java-type-in-jpa)